# want to extract runs from baalid and overid

Tags: mysql

<In the match with match id 335987, list the over ids and runs scored where at most 7 runs were scored. Order the over ids in decreasing order of runs scored. Resolve ties by listing the over ids in increasing order.>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to sum the runs_scored per over_id:

```sql
SELECT   over_id, SUM(runs_scored)
FROM     mytable
WHERE    match_id = 335987
GROUP BY over_id
HAVING   SUM(runs_scored) <= 7
ORDER BY SUM(runs_scored) DESC, over_id ASC
```